# Issue With JSON Object in Java?

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON Object which  converted into String and saved into database .But when i am trying to get it back it is throwing exception.My object is something like that...

```
{"COLUMN":["Type","Sub Type","F.P.","P.P.","Process","Due To Start"]}
```

How can we get the data back in Normal form?

My Java Code is.....

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray the_json_array = obj.getJSONArray(userReorderOption);
        int size = the_json_array.size();
        ArrayList<JSONObject> arrays = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            JSONObject another_json_object = the_json_array.getJSONObject(i);
            arrays.add(another_json_object);
        }
```

And Exception i am getting....

```
net.sf.json.JSONException: JSONObject["{\"TASKLIST_COLUMN_REORDER\":[\"Type\",\"Sub Type\",\"F.P.\",\"P.P.\",\"Process\",\"Due To Start\"]}"] is not a JSONArray.
```

And this is java Code how i am creating JSON Object and saving into database...

```
String userReorderSelection;  
  Set set = new LinkedHashSet(userReorderSelection);


        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.accumulate("COLUMN", set);
        saveJSONObj("PrimaryKeyColumn", json.toString());
```

Comment: what is the exception? Post it.

Comment: have you looked at the format in the database? is it the same as the string you tried to write? (Or do you need to escape it)

Comment: This is what what i got back from database.... 
 
{"COLUMN":["Type","Sub Type","F.P.","P.P.","Process","Due To Start"]}

Comment: I am getting this JSON Object  {"COLUMN":"[Sub Type, F.P., P.P., Process, Due To Start, Type]"} with New jar. Looking some issue,now when i am trying to get object back as a String i am getting Exception again....java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Tichodroma,
But as i told i am using `net.sf.json.JSONObject` class and above things we can achieve from this class too..What i did to solve the above issue?...Please have a look on the Java code...

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject obj  = jsonObj.fromObject(userReorderOption);
        JSONArray columnName = (JSONArray) obj.get("COLUMN");

        for (int i = 0; i < columnName.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(columnName.getString(i));

        }
```

This code work fine for me with my Json Jar**(net.sf.json)**

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is not a [`JSONArray`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html).

> A JSONArray is an ordered sequence of values.

You have a [`JSONObject`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html).

> A JSONObject is an unordered collection of name/value pairs.

**Edit:**

Using the JSON implementation from `org.codehaus.jettison.json`, you can do this:

```
String json = "{\"COLUMN\":[\"Type\",\"Sub Type\",\"F.P.\",\"P.P.\",\"Process\",\"Due To Start\"]}";

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
JSONArray column = (JSONArray) obj.get("COLUMN");

for (int i = 0; i < column.length(); i++) {
    final String field = column.getString(i);
    System.out.println(field);
}
```

Result:

```
Type
Sub Type
F.P.
P.P.
Process
Due To Start
```

Comment: Please let me know how can get value from my JSONObject to a list or StringBuffer

Comment: I am using net.sf.json.JSONObject class and when i m trying your code with Constructor like you defined. I am getting ...
The constructor JSONObject(String) is undefined.

Comment: Thanks i have to add org.codehaus.jettison.json Jar and it worked for me

Comment: I am getting another issue when i am trying to create JSON Object with new jar it is creating JSOn Object like this ...{"TASKLIST_COLUMN_REORDER":"[Sub Type, F.P., P.P., Process, Due To Start, Type]"} and when i am trying your code it is throwing case exception.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask a new one :) If you have more details for *this* question, please add them.

Comment: As you told me i changed my jar for JSON but with new jar when i am creating JSOn object it look like different than previous one so i am getting issue